# Mount multiple sub-apps with the same path in FastAPI

Tags: python, routes, fastapi

I have two fastapi sub apps, one called `api_app` and the other `admin_app`. I want to mount those 2 apps to my main app like that:

```py
app.mount('/', api_app, name='api')
app.mount('/', admin_app, name='admin_api')
```

When I try to access an endpoint from the app `admin_app` I get `Not Found` response.

I know this can be solved using `APIRouter` but in my case I need to use `FastAPI` app because I need to add middlwares to `api_app`.

I think the solution is to override the `404 exception handler` of the first app, but I don't know how to pass the request to the next app.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

try to add path name into your mounted app like:

```
app.mount('/api', api_app, name='api')
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your issue lies in assigning two apps on the same path, root (“/“).
As @ashkan mentioned if you provide any path different from the first app that should resolve this.